# Error occurs when installing Flask to my OSX Marverick

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Merverick OSX. I have installed Python 3.3.3 Into my computer and I would like to install Flask

When I type this in terminal

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

it says command not found

So I Try this one

```
$sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

and terminal shows this error to me

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-    
373.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

What does these error messages mean ?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.3.3?

Comment: I get the file from Python.org and install it into my application folder.

Comment: then I install the activeTCL that's it. Please help me otherwise I have to re-install the whole OSX because I have no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: How exactly did you install it, and which file did you download?

Comment: it is solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949882/flask-installation-doesnt-work-properly but maybe the new problem occur? or maybe not?> ^^"

Answer (score 0):

i 'm not in mac.But according to my poor english to this as follow,

> > 

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account using "sudo su".  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

it means you have no permission to write file '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-xxxx.And the terminal tell you to use root account to install.
Do a chmod a+x to '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/*'
So i hope it's useful to you and please read what was said by the terminal in detail:)

Comment: how can I use root account to install? and what is root account? Sorry I'm very new to this thing

Comment: can you use this command: sudo su ? sorry man, i 'm not familar with mac:)In other ways, you can change the mode of directory like this: sudo chmod -R 755 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Comment: It will install into python2.7? I would like to use it with my python 3.3. So I have to do it in different folder?

Comment: and how to do this? ^^"

Comment: I tried 

    Tammarats-MacBook-Air:~ Team$ $sudo chmod -R 755     
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

and it says this to me:

    chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Library/Python/2.7/site-
    packages/README: Operation not permitted

Comment: :(sorry,  i have lessons to do; Operation not permitted tell you the account (Tammarats-MacBook-Air) cannot access the directory;it looks like you should know what the root user is and This is http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528

Comment: so let us talk in email detailyang AT gmail.com or skype.

Comment: alright I understand, So I can follow this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US and  login as root user and then I can run this command right $sudo easy_install virtualenv ?