# Flask installation doesn't work properly

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Merverick OSX. I have installed Python 3.3.3 Into my computer and I would like to install Flask

When I type this in terminal

```
$sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

terminal shows this error to me

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-    
373.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

So I have access as root user and then type

```
$sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

and it says like this but there is a warning about *.egg what is that? something goes wrong? and how to fix it?

```
Last login: Wed Nov 13 16:10:17 on ttys000
Tammarats-MacBook-Air:~ Team$ su root
Password:
sh-3.2# $sudo easy_install virtualenv
Searching for virtualenv
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Best match: virtualenv 1.10.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-   
1.10.1.tar.gz#md5=3a04aa2b32c76c83725ed4d9918e362e
Processing virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
Running virtualenv-1.10.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-  
Nl7IVa/virtualenv-1.10.1/egg-dist-tmp-QGa1nR
warning: no files found matching '*.egg' under directory 'virtualenv_support'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory  
'docs/_templates'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
Adding virtualenv 1.10.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/bin
Installing virtualenv-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.10.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for virtualenv
Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: You can ignore those. :) Have you tried python -c "from flask import Flask" to see if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when we meet anything we cannot undestand like this, we should read the explainin detail。
did you find the "WARNING", it tell you it's not error; and

```
  Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.10.1-py2.7.egg    
  Processing dependencies for virtualenv
  Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv
```

tell the truth is that you have installed virtualenv successfully.
Now you can according the docs given by Flask, learn Flask;

Answer (score 1):

An issue is that the easy_install that is on the path is The Apple supplied one for python 2.7, so you have installed flask for python 2.7

You need to guve the explicit path to the python 3.3 version.

Also virtualenv is part of 3.3 see the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) soyou do not need to install it.

Answer (score -1):

For install vertualenv run this command : 
 **sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv** 
 and Flask installation follow these: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/   or 
 http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world .